# How do I use eclipse to build this application when it says you can use eclipse? sinch.com/tutorials/android-video-calling

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ide

How do I use eclipse to build this application when it says you can use eclipse? 
sinch.com/tutorials/android-video-calling

Thankyou and help would be appreciated

Comment: Why would you want to use eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse ADT plugin has been deprecated, you should use Android Studio for your project.
See http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2015/06/an-update-on-eclipse-android-developer.html